# Phpldapadmin not working with php

Tags: 16.04, server, php, ldap, apache2.4

For some reason my phpldapadmin doesn't want to work with my website and it says "If you are seeing this in your browser,
PHP is not installed on your web server!!!" Which is not true as if the info.php file is navigated to like [here](http://multicrew.co.uk/info.php) it says php is enabled along with the ldap extension. The apache error log doesn't say anything about the error though.

Every other php page on my website works except phpldapadmin. I am really confused.

Comment: where is your phpmyadmin root at?

Comment: Not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: check here `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: Yep its installed there

Comment: is your apache root `/var/www/` or `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: create a symbolic link from it to the apache root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my phpMyAdmin installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168191/where-is-my-phpmyadmin-installation)

Comment: I'm having problems with pypLDAPadmin not pypMYadmin

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that sorry, many apologies...

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)

Comment: Nope, still the same as before

Comment: I have installed phpldapadmin it just seems that it does not want to work with php, it just shows the source code not the proper page

Comment: Is your virtual host setup well?

Comment: It should be, all other php pages work on my site except for pypldapadmin

Comment: have you checked the permission?

Comment: The permission of?